# Bash scripts - is installing in this way good practice?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, yum

In my bash script I have the following lines installing various Linux packages on Centos 6.5 - two questions:

- is it good practice to do it this way?
- OR is there a better way maybe using rpms and how would I go about doing that?

  ```
  http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
  yum -y install update nano mlocate bind bind-utils php-mbstring aide psacct screen tmux iperf ipset rsync htop innotop dstat traceroute strace ltrace rkhunter nmap curl curl-devel php-pear php-xml php-devel gcc zlib-devel pcre-devel php zip unzip telnet php-imap vsftpd wget
  yum -y install perl-DateTime-Format-HTTP perl-DateTime-Format-Builder
  yum -y install php-pdo php-gd php-xml
  yum -y install expect
  rpm -Uvh --force ftp://ftp.univie.ac.at/systems/linux/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/perl-BerkeleyDB-0.43-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
  pecl install -f zip
  ```

Comment: Download an rpm and then `rpm -i file.rpm`

Comment: Using `--force` is essentially **never** correct.

Comment: Also `install update` is likely incorrect and you are probably seeing yum complain that `update` isn't a package it knows about.

Comment: Without the --force command it would stall the script and with it, it installed successfully - I don't remember what the issues were as it was a while back the script was written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, things will go faster if you simply combine all your `yum` commands into a single invocation:

```
yum -y install nano mlocate bind bind-utils \
  php-mbstring aide psacct screen tmux iperf ipset rsync \
  htop innotop dstat traceroute strace ltrace rkhunter \
  nmap curl curl-devel php-pear php-xml php-devel gcc \
  zlib-devel pcre-devel php zip unzip telnet php-imap \
  vsftpd wget perl-DateTime-Format-HTTP \
  perl-DateTime-Format-Builder php-pdo php-gd php-xml \
  expect
```

This way yum only needs to calculate dependencies once.

When installing an RPM from a remote server, you can *also* use yum:

```
yum -y install ftp://ftp.univie.ac.at/systems/linux/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/perl-BerkeleyDB-0.43-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

This will ensure that any dependencies of the package are installed as well.

Comment: Also, `yum` maintains metadata beyond what is maintained by `rpm`.  By using `yum` consistently you have access to things like `yum history rollback` that will not be available if you install packages with `rpm`.

Comment: Thank you - love your answer :)